# How to print nth line by replacing cut with sed

Tags: shell, sed, cut

I have to write a function taking as argument a csv file named players.csv and a number giving the line to print.
Indded, i have to print the nth line 2column and 3rd column with a "is" between. For example Mike is John. column delimeter is ";".
I have the following code which is working :

```
sed -n "$2p" players.csv | cut -d ";" -f 2,3 --output-delimiter=' is '
```

However, I have to do the same without using cut. I can only use sed and wc. Do you have any idea what sed command I can use to have the same behavior as with cut.
Thank you for your attention and your help.

Comment: Welcome on SO (which is not a free coding service). `sed` alone is enough. You already know how to limit its processing to the target line. Look at the substitute (`s`) command in the `sed` documentation and also at the regular expressions `sed` uses. Then, if you are stuck, please come back, show what you tried and explain what difficulty you encounter.

Comment: I tryed the following code : 
sed -n "$2p" players.csv | sed 's/[^;]*;\([^;]*\).*/\1/' && echo " is "
It is printing the 2nd column + is but i cant print the 3rd column after this and i dont know why.

Comment: @heyman you can edit your post and put your previous attempt in there. You can use backticks for writing line code: \`code\` becomes `code`.

Comment: @heyman Also, you should post some example input data, and an example of the output that you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there:

```
sed -En "$2"'s/[^;]*;([^;]*);([^;]*).*/\1 is \2/p' players.csv
```

Comment: Hey i tried your version and it is almost perfect. Indeed, when i compile with | cat -e i don't have the following$ after my expression if i take the last line of the csv. I don't know why it is only the case with the last one since it is working perfectly for the others.
Indeed i have the following line : Kyrie is UncleDrew instead of Kyrie is UncleDrew$
Thank you again for your help.

Comment: You probably don't have a newline at the end of your file. So `sed` does not change this and `cat -e` does not find the newline it needs to insert a `$`. Add the missing newline at the end of `players.csv`.

Comment: How to exit on `10th` line whatever it match `openssl ..... | sed -e '..' -e '..' -e '10p;q'` this exits with the first line i tried `-e '10q'` and it doesn't quite `openssl`, although when I use `q` with specific patren it works `-e '/^[0-9]\{10\}\,[0-9]\+.*/{q0};'`

Comment: @MamdouhSaeed If you have a question please create a new question, don't ask in a comment of a 1.5 years old answer.